# How do I fix this 'namespace not found error'?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013 for Windows Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3; adding the Lumia SensorCore SDK to develop an app. However the program complains, 'the type or namespace name 'Lumia' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

I have added the reference as the picture shows. In the MainPage.xaml.cs, there is a wiggly under Lumia.Sense. I can see Lumia.Sense in the References folder as well as I can see it in the Object Browser.

How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: Answer by JanR is correct. I need to get my eyes tested. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it looks like it's looking at your other project in the solution `HelloSensorSharp.Windows` not the `HelloSensorSharp.WindowsPhone` one. Check the reference in your first project and make sure the assembly exists and is referenced.